# Percentage of amount column

Tags: sql-server

I would like to add a column which shows percentage of amount but my query return 0 not percentage or decimals.

[image]

I need like this

[image]

SQL Query I am trying

```
SELECT  B_BRAND,
          B_QTY,
          B_QTY/(SELECT SUM(B_QTY)  FROM Table_B) AS PCENT
FROM Table_B
```

I need this with Group By actually.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing Integer / integer, which with SQL will give just an integer result.

`cast` as a decimal before hand - should give you the result you require

*100 to get to percentage.

```
SELECT  B_BRAND,
          B_QTY,
          cast(B_QTY as decimal(32,2))/cast(SUM(B_QTY) over ()  as decimal(32,2)) *100.00 AS PCENT
FROM Table_B
```

Comment: Thanks it's working but can you suggest me using Group By clause

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  B_BRAND,
          B_QTY,
          B_QTY * 1.0 / SUM(B_QTY) over() AS PCENT
FROM Table_B
```

Comment: Thanks its working but can you suggest me using Group By clause

Comment: Why with `group by`? Is it homework?

Comment: For the group by clause, use `B_QTY * 1.0 / SUM(B_QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY B_BRAND) AS PCENT`

Comment: Like This, Not working
SELECT  B_BRAND,
          SUM(B_QTY),
          B_QTY / SUM(B_QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY B_BRAND) AS PCENT
FROM Table_B

GROUP BY B_BRAND

Comment: @juergen No I am learning myself.